# How would I make a custom wave with JS?

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio

I have a wave I've created stored in an array like this: `[0, 1, 3, 6, 50, 90, 255, 90, 50, 6, 3, 1, 0, 1, 3]` and so on. How can I turn this into audio output using the web audio API?

Comment: I think you might find MDN's examples [on `AudioContext::createBuffer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createBuffer) and [on `AudioBuffer::copyToChannel()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer/copyToChannel) helpful. If you have difficulties, you can ask a question (or edit this one) about what specifically you don't understand.

Comment: @charlietfl You are incorrect. If you had actually checked the docs to verify your claim you likely would've come across these two very exposed pages. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Neither says you can't ask a "how to" question and the on-topic page clearly states that if the question is "a practical, answerable question that is unique to software development," then it is on topic.

Comment: Yes but there are also questions that are far too broad such as yours and what you are asking can be easily researched at least tto get a strating point. Research is also expected before asking .... and is a significant part of all developer's work load

Comment: @charlietfl I did research. I had a hard time understanding any of what I came across, even the MDN tutorials. That's why Stack Overflow exists. I did research, couldn't find an answer that I could understand, so I asked online myself. Then someone answered my question. I shouldn't have to provide proof that I did research before hand. If this was a question to help with debugging then I would've included code in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use a library such as RiffWave: https://gist.github.com/hackNightly/3776503
to make a wav data out of your array.

```
var wave = new RIFFWAVE();
wave.header.sampleRate = 8000;
wave.header.numChannels = 1;
wave.Make([0, 1, 3, 6, 50, 90, 255, 90, 50, 6, 3, 1, 0, 1, 3]);
var audioPlayback wave.dataURI;
```

Then you can create an HTML5 audio element and play the audio.

```
var audio1 = new Audio();
audio1.src = audioPlayback;
audio1.play();
```

The wave.dataURI is a base64 encoded data URI that you can assign to the src attribute of audio element just like that.

Comment: Very helpful and exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Happy to hear that.
I have used this library about an year ago to play a voice message on a chat application.